# setting environment variables using export are not accessible after relaunching command prompt in Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, environment-variables

I just downloaded maven, to install it, I am  setting environment variables using command line as described in documentation

```
export M2_HOME=/home/vishal/java/install/apache-maven
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

After this, I am able to check the maven version using 
    mvn --version.

But if I exit the command prompt and again launch it and type

```
mvn --version
```

It does not work.  If I again set environment variables, it works temporarily.

I tried adding environment variable in /etc/environment files also but still it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add them to your .bashrc file in your home directory.

```
 gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the lines you need at the end of the file, exactly as you were entering them before.  The file is executed every time you open a new terminal.  It will have the same effect as manually entering the commands every time you open a new shell.

Comment: I am new to linux, is it ok to add it at the end of file ? Is there any specific syntax I need to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables are added to the shell you just opened. They only live as long as the shell lives.

If you want them to be persistent you have to make sure they are loaded every time. As someone else answered, add those lines to your ~/.bashrc